# упал поиск(sphinx), сайт на ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, sphinxsearch

Здравствуйте! Есть сайт, написан на ror (rails --version не показывает). Для поиска на сайте используется sphinx, его последние логи:

```
[Mon May 23 19:02:58.650 2016] [ 2605] rotating index 'tourist_attraction_core': success
[Mon May 23 19:02:58.650 2016] [ 2605] rotating index 'tour_core': started
[Mon May 23 19:02:58.850 2016] [ 2605] rotating index 'tour_core': success
[Mon May 23 19:02:58.850 2016] [ 2605] rotating index 'post_core': started
[Mon May 23 19:02:59.267 2016] [ 2605] rotating index 'post_core': success
[Mon May 23 19:02:59.267 2016] [ 2605] rotating index: all indexes done
[Mon May 23 19:41:17.603 2016] [ 2605] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon May 23 19:41:18.437 2016] [ 2605] shutdown complete
[Mon May 23 19:48:07.773 2016] [ 2764] Child process 2765 has been forked
[Mon May 23 19:48:07.774 2016] [ 2765] listening on 127.0.0.1:9332
[Mon May 23 19:48:08.304 2016] [ 2765] binlog: replaying log /srv/gotoural/admin/tmp/binlog/production/binlog.001
[Mon May 23 19:48:08.308 2016] [ 2765] FATAL: binlog: update: descending tid (index=(null), lasttid=2, logtid=1, pos=135)
[Mon May 23 19:48:08.309 2016] [ 2764] Child process 2765 has been finished, exit code 1. Watchdog finishes also. Good bye!
```

Упал он действительно так давно, я пытался локально поднять сайт, чтобы покопаться в этом всём, но он тупо не собирается, там куча зависимостей, некоторые из них deprecated, короче ад полный.

Из логов-то я понимаю, что он просто выключился, но как теперь его запустить?

Вообще эта проблема уже возникала, я решил сам поправить это, через SSH попробовал запустить sphinx, в итоге сайт намертво лёг, что к чему - непонятно. Разработчики тогда помогли его поднять, но вообще они уже немного сердились, потому что их часто просили что-нибудь "прикрутить".

Сайт какой-то вообще хрупкий, я даже ребут в надежде поднятия поиска боюсь делать, вдруг ещё что не встанет, может можно как-то поиск врубить не трогая сайт?
В /etc/default/sphinxsearch START=yes стоит.

/srv/gotoural/admin/tmp/binlog/production/binlog.001

```
SPBL^D^@^@^@TXN!^C^@^@^A▒^▒^▒▒^▒▒▒^B^G^Kf▒TXN!^B^@^A▒^▒^▒▒^▒▒▒^B^A^Nsphinx_deleted^A^A^A^@^@^@^A▒^K^@^@^A^@^@^@^@;]▒▒TXN!^B^@^B▒^▒▒▒^▒▒▒^B^A^Nsphinx_del$
TXN!^B^@^A▒▒^▒^Ψ▒▒^B^A^Nsphinx_deleted^A^A^A^@^@^@^A▒ ^@^@^A^@@^@^A▒ ;▒^üTXN!^B^@^A▒^ͯɨ▒▒^B^A^Nsphinx_deleted^A^A^A^@^@^@^A▒
^@^@^A^@^@^@^@▒k9^▒TXN!^B^@^A▒^Ӽ޺▒▒^B^A^Nsphinx_deleted^A^A^A^@^@^@^A$^M^@^@^A^@^@^@^@
▒▒1TXN!^B^@^A▒▒▒^▒^▒▒^B^A^Nsphinx_deleted^A^A^A^@^@^@^A^▒^M^@^@^A^@^@^@^@h)$'TXN!^B^@^Aꮷ^▒▒▒▒^B^A^Nsphinx_deleted^A^A^A^@^@^@^A▒^M^@^@^A^@^@^@^@▒^Gb▒$
^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^▒'^▒TXN!^B^@^B^▒^▒▒▒^▒▒▒^B^A^Nsphinx_deleted^A^A^A^@^@^@^A^▒
^@^@^A^@^@^@^@4Zv▒TXN!^B^@^A^ĵ▒▒▒▒^B^A^Nsphinx_deleted^A^A^A^@^@^@^A^G^F^@^@^A^@^@^@^@▒^▒▒▒TXN!^B^@^A^▒^▒^«▒▒▒^B^A^Nsphinx_deleted^A^A^A^@^@^@^A▒^O^@$
```

Comment: [Первый найденный топик](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=8925) советует почистить бинлоги сфинкса. Сработает ли это, неизвестно. Не думаю, что мы со своей стороны сможем сделать что-то ещё, код-то ваш, и публиковать его у вас права наверняка нет.

Comment: Мне бы понять, что делать после очистки логов, сфинкс ведь просто так не запустится. А доступ, как мне кажется,  должен быть, ведь у меня есть рутовые права.

Comment: В вопросе нет вообще никакой информации, позволяющей дать на это ответ.

Comment: А какая информация могла бы помочь?

Comment: Трудно сказать. Есть какой-то абстрактный сервер на какой-то абстрактной ОС, на которой работает какое-то абстрактное приложение из каких-то абстрактных компонентов, связанных каким-то абстрактным образом. Один из этих абстрактных компонентов выключился, и вы интересуетесь, как его включить.